# Limiting redirected Paypal payment with a certain email address

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a business requirement which is to not let user enter different email address other than his own which used on the platform which redirects to a Paypal payment system. Is there a way in Paypal API to achieve this effect? Like inputting an email address which must be entered before redirecting user to Paypal system.

I've done small research on Paypal API couldn't find anything that suits my needs. I might have missed it.